# PDF IText | ClassCastException - com.lowagie.text.Paragraph cannot be cast to com.lowagie.text.Table

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I am using com.lowagie.text.xml.SAXiTextHandler to convert XML to PDF using iText(v - 2.1.7). I get the below error although i can see that i am using the tags correctly. Verified that the XML formed is valid and i can view it in browser w/o errors. Code fails when trying to do the a parser.parse(....). I have checked the way i have written the tags and it looks fine to me. I have basically added table tags, containing row tags which inturn contains cell tags.
Cell tags have a single paragraph tag inside it (or) sometimes a paragraph and a chunk tag within the paragraph. Is there any way I can get to where this issue happens?

*** Removed all the paragraph tags from the XML and tried again. It is returning the same error -  Here is the new XML used - http://pastebin.com/hmyPcGDw ***

*** Even this simple xml file is generating the same exception now - http://pastebin.com/89U9vybt ***

To me it looks like an issue with com.lowagie.text.xml.SAXiTextHandler. Any help ?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.lowagie.text.Paragraph cannot be cast to com.lowagie.text.Table
        at com.lowagie.text.xml.SAXiTextHandler.handleEndingTags(Unknown Source)
        at com.lowagie.text.xml.SAXiTextHandler.endElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:606)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endNamespaceScope(XMLDTDValidator.java:2054)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:2005)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:879)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1741)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2898)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:302)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
```

Comment: could you post your xml please?

Comment: Here is the xml - http://pastebin.com/qJsDkj4G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you have some white space before and after your xml tags (**more precisely the white spaces after the `<table>` tag**). I tried with your example and i had the same exception. I made a copy/paste of your xml code into eclipse (or notepad++) i formatted it (that removes all the unwanted white space) and then i tried again and the problem was solved! the pdf is well generated!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Well, I tried it on the simple ones and it worked for me too. The problem i am facing now is with a 2000+ line XML.I eyeballed for whitespace from  <table> tag till </table> tag and removed them. Still i am getting the error. Should i not have any whitespace(both tab/blank space) after a start tag and end tag? Could you please let me know the guideline here and how to easily remove unwanted whitespace ?

Comment: You shouldn't have spaces after the `<table>` tag (there is a bug in `com.lowagie.text.xml.SAXiTextHandler`). To remove whitespaces, you can copy/paste your xml code in `eclipse` and then `ctrl + a` to select all your code then `ctrl + shift + f` to format it. Or if you are using notepad++, install the "XML Tools" plugin (Menu Plugins, Plugin Manager) then run: Menu Plugins, Xml Tools, Pretty Print (XML only - with line breaks).